# HTML5 Video plays on iPhone iOS but not on Desktop Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video, typo3

I am developing a Typo3 site and have installed "html5videoplayer" extension. Then I added the videos in MP4, .ogg and webm format, as this should cover all the browsers and also iPhone/iPad. However, it worked on iPhone/iPAD, and also chrome, opera, firefox and IE, but just wont work on SAFARI!

Here is the html:

```
<div class="video-js-box ">
<video id="video_1" class="video-js " width="960" height="450" data-setup="{}" controls="" autoplay="" preload="auto" tabindex="0">
<source type="video/mp4" src="fileadmin/Videos/Canebio_Korr.mp4"></source>
<source type="video/webm" src="fileadmin/Videos/canebio_mobile.webm"></source>
<source type="video/ogg" src="fileadmin/Videos/Canebio_Korr.ogg"></source>
</video>
<p class="vjs-no-video"> </p>
</div>
```

Any suggestion, ideas will be highly appreciated. You can also view the site at http://tinyurl.com/c7gunen

Thank you

Comment: Update: I included the Static Template HTML5 Video Player and now it playes in Safari but stopped playing in Firefox, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Did the server send the files with a correct mime type?

.htacces in the folder with the video files:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```